# Could we lighten up the Google+ icon a little?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, design

Don't get me wrong, but I'm getting slightly annoyed by the tiny Google+ icon right below the voting controls, in the er... social bar. The size is OK, but the color... well:

[image: The icon]

I swear, at first I thought it was a bounty added to the question. We are used to see red elements as important stuff, but I don't know, the G+ color is quite distracting.

Both Facebook and Twitter icons have light colors, almost as if blending to the background. But the G+ one is certainly drawing my attention. It's screaming "look at me look at me!" `:)`

I'd like to suggest to lighten up the icon a little, like the following image:

[image: Color]

It looks more discreet to me.

Sorry for the rant. It's the red color effect. `:)`

Comment: It seems that the state of your request is "status-declined": http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120436/would-the-new-share-buttons-benefit-from-being-grey

Comment: @lockstep: wow, you *are* fast! `:)` Maybe @Jin could lighten up the Google+ icon for us; the other icon blend nicely.

Comment: Indeed, the red icon is too eye-catching! Having it a little less red would be better. Ironically I was the guy which [requested it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97406/any-plans-supporting-google-for-link-sharing-in-the-near-future) (however, not in any specific color).

Comment: Well, but perhaps it will persuade Jin & Co that requests are coming from various sites all over the network. I entirely share your resentment against the color.

Comment: @Martin: the Google+ icon is a very good idea! `:)` Maybe the current icon would look better on a dark theme based SE site, like Gaming. `:)`

Comment: @doncherry: I think the color change is doable. `:)` I removed my other suggestion of moving the social bar elsewhere, so Jeff won't kill me. `:)`

Comment: Sorry about all the confusion. :) As you can see, we spoke directly with our designer. I hope you're all happy with the result. :D

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have desaturated the red in G+ by 30%. It will be in the next production build. (you may have to do a hard refresh).

Comment: Thank you (and some filler).

Comment: For anyone wondering why it was desaturated rather than lightened, see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2216/make-the-google-less-distracting-by-syncing-its-saturation-with-the-other-icons.

Answer (score 12):

Another option is to use an ad-filtering browser plugin and flag the offending icon as an ad. Then you don't have to look at anything you find too overtly attention-seeking.

Comment: Good idea! I've never thought of that. `:)`

Comment: This worked great at first, but now the horizontal rules for the main navigation bar won't load.

Answer (score 0):

What about "inverting" it? A quick mockup: [image]